# parsing json using JSON.parse() throws error

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have big json string that is decoded from decodeURIComponent() function. Now I am trying to parse this string to Json object using JSON.parse() function. When i run, it says 'unexpected syntax token m'. I have two doubts here
1. Is there any better tool to get the syntax corrections as it is a large string.
2. When I give the same json string to validate in this url "http://jsonviewer.stack.hu", I am getting valid json object.. how is this possible.

The valid json object which I m getting in point 2 is what I would need in my program. Please give me some suggestions on how to resolve this.

here is my json string: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz0478Hh7tBqS0pXUTBMTVFPZzA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: that is not json, that is a javascript variable assignment statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'm' it is complaining about is the first character. You need to remove the `mandrill_events=` part at the beginning for it to be valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use the npm package `jsonlint` for validation of large JSON files.

```
npm install -g jsonlint
```

Usage is straightforward and it will tell you precisely where the JSON violation exists.

```
Usage: jsonlint [file] [options]

file     file to parse; otherwise uses stdin

Options:
   -v, --version            print version and exit
   -s, --sort-keys          sort object keys
   -i, --in-place           overwrite the file
   -t CHAR, --indent CHAR   character(s) to use for indentation  [  ]
   -c, --compact            compact error display
   -V, --validate           a JSON schema to use for validation
   -e, --environment        which specification of JSON Schema the validation
                            file uses  [json-schema-draft-03]
   -q, --quiet              do not print the parsed json to STDOUT  [false]
   -p, --pretty-print       force pretty printing even if invalid
```

Comment: Or just http://jsonlint.com/ I suppose if you can't be bothered to install node and npm

Comment: Sure, that works too when you have an internet connection. The command line tool is nice to have in your toolbox though, as it can do various transformations to JSON content. I quite like working on the command line though.

Answer (score 0):

`mandrill_events=` in the beginning is what's breaking `JSON.parse(...)`. Remove that.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question about the tool, I like this one.

http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

Just paste yout JSON and press the right arrow. I works in both directions and you can edit the JSON on the right hand side as well.

If there is a problem with your JSON object, it will tell you where exactly. It uses jsonlint under the hood.

In your case, the problem might be the initial variable assignment as other answers said, as that is not valid JSON. You need to remove that, an leave just the array. JSON Editor Online throws this error, which is more descriptive.

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:
mandrill_events=[{"e
^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'
```

Hope this helps.